# Is the error message picture from "Alice in Wonderland"?

Tags: discussion

Is the error message picture for the English Stack Exchange from "Alice in Wonderland"?

[image: English Stack Exchange error screenshot]

Comment: The custom error/404 pages of Alice have gone. Replaced by the outline of a hazard sign. What is happening to creativity and sensibility on Stack Exchange? Where's the fun? The charm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is, same for the [404 page](https://english.stackexchange.com/404) and the [CAPTCHA page](https://english.stackexchange.com/captcha) images.

[Source](http://fithfath.com/images/?p=345).

Answer (score 10):

My guess would be NO, it is from *Through the Looking Glass*.  You see: *Alice in Wonderland* has playing cards, while the sequel *Through the Looking Glass* has chess pieces.

Comment: Yes, that looks like something from the first chapter of *Through the Looking Glass*, though I haven't got it handy now.

Comment: I think you're correct! I was just thinking "Alice" in general.